# Value not persisting when using didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift

Hi im trying to pass a variable to another view controller from my tableview within the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` func:

```
class MessagesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

        @IBOutlet var messagesTableView: UITableView!
        @IBOutlet var invitesButton: UIButton!

        var messagesTableViewDataSource: MessagesTableViewDatasource = MessagesTableViewDatasource()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            messagesTableView.dataSource = self.messagesTableViewDataSource

            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false

            let titleView = NavTitleView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 122, height: 32))
            titleView.title = "Messages"
            self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView

        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            let cell: MessageCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! MessageCell
            let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ConversationViewController") as! ConversationViewController
            viewController.conversationUUID = cell.conversationUUID
            viewController.conversationProfileImage = cell.senderProfileImage
        }

        @IBAction func invitesButtonWasPressed() {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("segueToInvites", sender: self)
        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        }
    }
```

here is where the cell is built:

```
        class MessagesTableViewDatasource: NSObject, UITableViewDataSource {

        var messages: [InboundMessage] = []

        func createMessagesArray(message: InboundMessage) {
            self.messages.append(message)
        }

        func loadMessages() -> [InboundMessage] {
            if self.messages.count > 0 {
                return self.messages
            } else {
                InboundMessage.all { messages in
                    messages.forEach(self.createMessagesArray)
                }
                return self.messages
            }
        }

        func createTableViewFooter(tableView: UITableView) {

            let footer = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width - 100, tableView.bounds.size.height))
            footer.text = "You have no more messages."
            footer.textAlignment = .Center
            footer.textColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.25)
            footer.font = Style.smallFont
            footer.sizeToFit()
            tableView.tableFooterView = footer
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            loadMessages()
            createTableViewFooter(tableView)

            let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
            dateFormatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
            dateFormatter.timeStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle

            let cell: MessageCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MessageCell") as! MessageCell
            cell.senderName.text = messages[indexPath.row].senderName
            cell.senderText.text = messages[indexPath.row].senderText
            cell.timeMessageReceived.text = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(messages[indexPath.row].timeAndDateMessageReceived)
            cell.conversationUUID = messages[indexPath.row].conversationUUID

            if (messages[indexPath.row].senderProfileImageName != nil) {
                cell.senderProfileImage!.image = UIImage(named: messages[indexPath.row].senderProfileImageName)
            }
            if (messages[indexPath.row].hasBeenRead == false) {
                cell.unOpenedImage!.image = UIImage(named: "RedDot")
            }

            return cell
        }

        func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            loadMessages()
            if self.messages.count == 0 {
                let noMessagesLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, tableView.bounds.size.height))
                noMessagesLabel.text = "You have no messages at the moment."
                noMessagesLabel.textAlignment = .Center
                noMessagesLabel.sizeToFit()
                tableView.backgroundView = noMessagesLabel
                tableView.separatorStyle = .None

                return 0
            }
            return 1
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
            return 50
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return messages.count
        }

    }
```

but when i get back to my view controller the values are nil and i don't understand why. Here is the view controller it gets passed to:

```
class ConversationViewController: UIViewController {

        @IBOutlet var conversationTableView: UITableView!

        var conversationTableViewDataSource: ConversationTableViewDataSource = ConversationTableViewDataSource()
        var conversationUUID: NSUUID!
        var conversationProfileImage: UIImageView!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            conversationTableView.dataSource = self.conversationTableViewDataSource
            conversationTableViewDataSource.conversationUUID = self.conversationUUID
            conversationTableViewDataSource.conversationProfileImage = self.conversationProfileImage

            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.translucent = false

    //        let titleView = NavTitleView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 122, height: 32))
    //        titleView.title = "Messages"
    //        self.navigationItem.titleView = titleView

        }

        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        }
    }
```

I'm sure, i'm missing something simple but as i'm pretty new to all this i can't find it after much googling and was hoping for some insight.

Thanks

Comment: are you using segues?

Comment: and how you go to `ConversationViewController` ?

Comment: There is no code of pushViewController.

Comment: Hi, sorry, i have added the full files. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Still there is no code of navigation.

Comment: Check before navigation, what you getting from cell.conversationUUID , it may possible it is nil .

Comment: when i put a breakpoint at  'viewController.conversationProfileImage = cell.senderProfileImage' i get 'conversationUUID = (NSUUID!) 0x7af36e70'

Comment: @NDoc i thought i had set that in the storyboard. Or am i missing something?

Comment: Have you created segue in your storyboard? with your tableCell, if yes what is the identifier of segue?

Comment: yes, i believe i drag and dropped from the cell in messages view controller to conversation view controller and then chose 'show' from the dropdown menu @NDoc the identifier is segueToConversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `prepareForSegue` method for that add `prepareForSegue` method inside your `MessagesViewController`

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "segueToConversation") {
        let destVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ConversationViewController
        let cell = sender as! MessageCell
        destVC.conversationUUID = cell.conversationUUID
        destVC.passImage = cell.senderProfileImage.image
    }
}
```

**Note:** You cannot directly assign image to `UIImageView` object `conversationProfileImage` because it is not initialized yet, so that create on instance of `UIImage` in the `ConversationViewController` with name `passImage` as i written in answer an then use that image object in `viewDidLoad` to assign image to `UIImageView`.

Comment: Amazing, thanks. I tried to use prepareForSegue but it kept opening up another buttons segue. Now from looking at your code i understand i need to pick the segue using an identifier. Thank you!